# Query data from a remote host using influxdb python client

Tags: python, database, influxdb, influxdb-python

I just started using Influxdb and I'm kind of lost on how to access a remote host in order to query some data from the data base and put the imported data in a data frame.

I found in the documentation, the following lines to access influxdb of a remote host and to query the data:

```
 client = InfluxDBClient(host='mydomain.com', port=8086, username='myuser', password='mypass' ssl=True, verify_ssl=True)
 client.query('SELECT "duration" FROM "pyexample"."autogen"."brushEvents" WHERE time > now() - 4d GROUP BY "user"')
```

My problem:

1- I don't know how to get the 'host' and 'port' values for the remote host.

2-If you can provide a small example on how to query the data from the data base and store it in a data frame, that would be nice.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Check out https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-python-influxdb/

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't really help you determine the remote host name without more information about the remote host. You need the name/ip/domain of the computer hosting InfluxDB. 8086 is the default port. Can you ask the person that set up InfluxDB on the remote host?